Discord bot with python issue
i have this code:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN='BOT TOKEN'
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} online')

@bot.command(name='hello')
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('hello')

bot.run(TOKEN)

your text
And I don't know why the bot responded to my dms command but it didn't respond on every channel I tried on my servers
I would appreciate it if someone could help me
I checked the accesses and it has accesses to send messages and to read and I also put an administrator and it still didn't work

Do you have message content intent privileged gateway intent turned on for your bot in discord developer portal? And does the bot have messages.read oauth2 scope?
